# Get youtube video's title

Tags: php, youtube

I've make a simple code to have the title of a video youtube in PHP and JSON, but I have a problem now.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/';
    $vid = $video['video_id'];
    $end = '?format=5&alt=json';
    $response = file_get_contents($url.$vid.$end);
    $obj = json_decode($response);
?>
<?php print_r($obj->entry->title); ?>
```

My `print_r` print this :

> stdClass Object ( [$t] => Title of the video [type] => text )

How I am suppose to get this `$t`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `json_decode` with second parameter set to `true`, this will make an associative array instead of `stdClass` object. Then print it like that:

```
json_decode($response, true);
print_r($obj['entry']['title']['$t'];
```

Comment: Because `YouTube API` returns up to 25 videos in one call and you need loop to iterate over that collection. Without loop you'd need to read `$item[0]`, `$item[1]` and so on. With loop you can simply read i-th element or in foreach read i-th element as variable.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$obj = json_decode($response, true);
foreach($obj['data']['items'] as $item) {
    echo $item['title'];
    echo $item['description'];
    echo $item['rating'];
    echo $item['player']['default'];
    // whatever you need....
}
```